# What are the "official" logos to use when designing an Android and iOS App?

Tags: mobile, android, ios, download, logos

When displaying logos showing that your service is available on mobile app stores, what are the correct logos and names to be used for:

- Apple App Store
- Google Play Store

I knew what they were before but I don't know where to go to check this as, after typing them into Google, there seem to be many variants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android has an official [guide](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/brand.html) from Google.

And iTunes [too](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#)

So, to avoid Copyrights issues and all kind of related stuff I suggest to follow their guidelines.

Comment: Can't go wrong following official guidelines.